# CSS Flicker/ Blinking logo trick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flicker

Hi I have a logo in a variety of colours that I want to use in a random/ erratic deliberate flicker effect. I could only find other articles about doing blinking tricks with the fadein/ fadeout function. Any ideas on how to do such a trick with css3 and/ or jQuery? I have also seen similar discussions using Math_Floor to randomise a sort of strobing effect but it wasn't quite what I was after.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're working with?

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please do not use its tag for graphical logos.

Comment: Something like this http://css-tricks.com/glitch-effect-text-images-svg/ ?

Comment: I assume you would need something to change the logo too? Except from the blinking effect.

Comment: Thanks joews, that's sort of getting closer.

Comment: Sidney, here is the html, just bare bones at the moment <!--loading page index html-->
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!--<meta name="description" content="Saffron Reichenbacker" /> 
 <meta name="keywords" content="Saffron Reichenbacker, Norffas, lo-brow, no-brow, Brighton Artists" />-->
 
 <!--<img src="NorffasRed1.jpg" id="bg" alt="">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<title>Norffas</title>


<body>
 <div id="bg">
  <img src="NorffasRed1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<!--<div class="logo"></div>-->
</body>
</html>

Comment: and here is the css #bg {
  position: 100%; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

Comment: the idea being that I have a range of different coloured logos/ jpegs that I could run to create an erratic flickering effect

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this?

```css
.blink {
  animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -o-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
This is <span class="blink">blinking</span> text.
```